# NodeJs Prisma double include property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I have 3 model schemas in my project:

1. Vendors: id + name
2. Items: id + name + vendorId
3. categories: id + name + ItemId

I need to create a prisma query schema that allows me to retrieve categories including details of the item and the vendor.

the prisma models:

```
model Vendor {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String  @db.VarChar(255)
  Item Item[]
  @@map("Vendors")
}

model Item {
  id             Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name           String    @db.VarChar(255)
  vendor         Vendor    @relation(fields: [vendorId], references: [id])
  vendorId       Int
  Category Category[]
  @@map("Items")
}

model Category {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String   @db.VarChar(255)
  item       Item     @relation(fields: [itemId], references: [id])
  itemId     Int

  @@map("Categories")
}
```

The express endpoint is as follows:

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let items = await prisma.Category.findMany({
            include: {
               item: true
            },
        });

        res.status(200).json(items)
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(error.message);
    }

});
```

The code as is now, it will return a list of categories along with the items of each category, however, the item will include the vendorId instead of vendor details. What should I add to the code to get vendor details without the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `vendors` along with `items` while fetching category through this query.

```js
  let items = await prisma.category.findMany({
    include: {
      item: {
        include: {
          vendor: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  console.log(items);
```

Here's the sample response for the query:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mobile",
    "itemId": 1,
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Iphone",
      "vendorId": 1,
      "vendor": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple Inc"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! you practically saved my life!!! I voted up to all your posts as thanks!

Comment: Haha, No worries! Glad I could help. But those other upvotes will be reversed by StackOverflow as they do not recommend doing it.